# What is meant by partial failure feature in TestNG?

Tags: testng

I've learned that this is one of the feature of TestNG along with parallel testing and Load Testing.

Learned some thing about this [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=bCvcMcLZwV4C&pg=PT96&lpg=PT96&dq=what%20is%20partial%20failure%20feature&source=bl&ots=84HFsEVNoA&sig=3UOJpK12lPNbvDJmtySHFcAFdDQ&hl=en&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjLu_3F4dvMAhULMo8KHWYLCusQ6AEILTAD#v=onepage&q=what%20is%20partial%20failure%20feature&f=false) but didn't get what was mentioned in it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature called **Soft Assertion**. I think, this feature resembles to partial failure feature.